# How to resolve merge pull request conflict for .DS_Store the easiest way?

Tags: git, github, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm fairly new to Git and Github and also gotten very confused at Git's vast array of command line. Today I push my commit like usual and create a pull request. But when my coworker tries to merge, it shows:

> This branch has conflicts that must be resolved
>
> Use command line to resolve conflicts before continuing.
>
> Conflicting files
>
> .DS_Store

I would like to resolve this using steps as simple as possible. I used subversion SVN in the past, and it has a very easy solution: "use 'theirs' version" or "use 'mine' version". I would like to be able to right click somewhere, and choose "use 'theirs' version" on this `.DS_Store` file, and don't care with whatever its contents is. All I want is for the conflict to go away. I don't know where I can find that feature in Github. I've tried to browse Git command lines for this, but I don't know exactly which one to use. The problem is, this is pull request merge conflict, which 'happened' at the server. My commit that has the .DS_Store is the 2nd last commit. The last commit on my branch is a "rebase" from the master branch. So if I want to revert to my commit, I will have to revert the rebase commit as well, and I don't know what's the side effect of it (won't I be able to do a "rebase" again because I have already do a "rebase"? I don't know). I can't solve this at my or my coworker's computer because I can't pull the conflict from the master branch from the server to my local computer. How should I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Personally I delete all `.DS_Store` files and then add them to my repo's `.gitignore` file. They're just meta data files which get can be recreated anyway.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I solved it by first force to bring the conflict to branch using command line, and then using `rm --cached`. after that I add it to git ignore like what you did. but first I need to bring the conflict to branch, which was the main problem in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with pull request. I found this answer on the Internet and it helped me. It implies a simple deletion of this file from the computer and a new commit.

```
find . -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 git rm -f --ignore-unmatch
git add .gitignore
git commit -m '.DS_Store banished!'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using macOS, your system appends the .DS_Store file in your directories. It’s not a big issue, but often you need to exclude these files explicitly in your .gitignore file, to prevent any unnecessary files in your commit.

You may want to ignore this file globally, so next time you don’t need to add it to your project’s ignore list.

`git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore`

`echo .DS_Store >> ~/.gitignore`